# Почему не работает унаследованная форма?

Tags: python, django

помогите пожалуйста исправить процесс авторизации.

я создаю форму AuthenticationCustomForm (наследуя от AuthenticationForm):
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

```
class AuthenticationCustomForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label='Имя пользователя',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Логин',
        }),     
    )

    password = forms.CharField(
        label='Пароль', 
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Пароль',
        }),
    )
```

views.py:

```
def login(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        form = AuthenticationCustomForm(request.POST)
        with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "1.txt"), "wb") as f:
            f.write(bytes('1', 'UTF-8'))        
        if form.is_valid():
            with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "2.txt"), "wb") as f:
                f.write(bytes('2', 'UTF-8'))            
            username = request.POST.get('username', '')
            password = request.POST.get('password', '')

            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/' + str(request.user.pk) + '/')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationCustomForm()   

    t = loader.get_template('accounts/login.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form, 
    }, [custom_proc])   
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

login.html:
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.error }}
    {% endfor %}

```
<form class="login_form" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="cell">
        {{ form.username }}

        {{ form.username.errors }}

         {{form.non_field_errors}}
    </div>  

    <div class="cell">
        {{ form.password }}

        {{ form.password.errors }}

         {{form.non_field_errors}}
    </div>              

    <div class="cell">
        <input class="submit btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Войти" />
    </div>
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'views.login', name='login', ),
```

в результате пользователь не может войти через эту форму даже если вводит правильные логин и пароль(остаётся на этом же экране, сообщение об ошибке валидации на экран не выводится). при этом создаётся отладочный файл "1.txt", но не создаётся "2.txt"

нельзя ли предложить решение, основанное на стандартной логике для данной ситуации? не используя приёмы ниндзя(на стековерфлоу [предложили](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534615/why-does-not-work-in-the-form-of-validation) пока только такие. причем они криво работают)

Comment: Так вам же предложили - проверьте ошибки формы. Логин/пароль верные для проверки:

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

но до нее же дело не доходит. Для примера: у вас на форме стоит минимальная длина для логина 6 символов, а в логине всего 5 символов